# Node link not working

Tags: java, search, freemarker, jcr, magnolia

I want to link my results from searchfn to the page, not only to the component.
At the moment I have:

```
[#if queryStr?has_content]
    [#assign searchResults = mySearchfn.searchContent('website', queryStr, '/home', 'mgnl:component') /]
[#assign recordsFound = searchResults?size /]

        <h3>  <em>${recordsFound}</em> Results -> "${queryStr}"</span></h3>

    <div class="list-group">
    [#if searchResults?has_content]
        [#list searchResults as item]
        <a href="${cmsfn.link(item)}" class="list-group-item">
            <p class="list-group-item-text">${item.excerpt!}</p>
            </a>


        <p class="list-group-item-text">${item.page!}</p>
        <!--return:getPath() of the node (pointing to component) as String-->
        <p class="list-group-item-text">${item.pageLink!}</p>
        <!--return:path/to/page as String-->

        [/#list]
    [/#if]
        </div>

[/#if]
```

the url I get from  tag is something like "path/to/page/area/component", the problem is I can't see the full page, only the component.

```
<a href="${cmsfn.contentByPath(item.pageLink, "website")}">link</a>
```

given the example above, only builds the url as /page not building with full string (path/to/page)

Answer (score 0):

Either

- use `searchPages(String query, String startPath)` instead or
- change last param in your code to be `mgnl:page` instead of `mgnl:component` (as the last param is the return type not the search type).

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

${cmsfn.link(cmsfn.page(item))}

or:

${cmsfn.link(cmsfn.contentByPath(item.pageLink))}